Soldering RG179 coaxial cable directly to PCB
I'm building a very low-cost bidirectional SDI-3G to fiber converter. I am in the process of selecting a connector for the SDI part. The issue is that I can't really find one that won't explode the budget. The latest fully assembled prototype is somewhere around 30 €.
After some research on DigiKey for a right angle 75 Ω BNC connector, here is what came out:

The SCNBN-J1175-SORBP (2.6 €). This is the cheapest I could find, but I'm not sure if it can handle the signal and what losses.
The UCBBJE20-1 (4.37 €). This is the next best thing. I'm pretty sure it would do the job fine and will take less space, but the price is pretty high.

One option I'm considering is to use BNC pigtails (that I already have,) cut the cable and directly solder the RG179 to the PCB. Even if I were to buy them, it would be in the 2 € per connector.
I saw a few questions about this, namely:

Soldering RG-405 coaxial cable directly to PCB pads meant for U.FL connector
Is there a standardized foot print for attaching coax cable directly to a board?
Can I solder a RG316 coax directly to a PCB instead of using the intended SMA connectors?
Best way to connect coax along a microstrip

Obviously, this means that the cable will no longer be removable, but that is not an issue. Mechanical stress isn't one either because I don't expect the cable to be handled/touched.
My concern is about signal integrity, potential losses, etc. It has clearly been done before (especially in low-cost products) but I couldn't find a lot of documentation about the side-effects.

What's preventing you from testing a prototype with soldered connections?

Nothing, in fact, it is planned, but I want to know if there is an obvious or huge dis-advantage for doing it

How many are you going to be making?  An expensive part might be worth not having a lot of manual hassle.

Something like 10, it wouldn't even be a question if it was more. But for such a low run I'm fine with taking the time.

What Neil said. If you need good behaviour over 1 GHz, maybe build some test boards with 75 ohm microstrip and 75 ohm resistor, and test with a VNA. For RG179 you can probably just solder to the face of the board, but also consider having a short slot with plated edges, for the braid. Finally, my standard method for planar attachment was always to cut the jacket back about 12 mm, unwrap the braid and then *twist it around to form a.tight, fat bundle about 4 mm long. Strip 3 mm of the inner. This way the braid bundle is as thick as the jacket so it touches down on the board.

There is generally no electrical/RF problem when soldering coax to a board. Even if the foot print dimensions approach a significant fraction of the wavelength or rise-time distance, you will generally be able to match the transition.
The problems are almost entirely mechanical.

You will probably need to strip and prepare the coax yourself. You may be able to buy a prepared tail, but as it is 'unusual' and may have to be custom, it may be more expensive than a machine-fitted connector
Strain relief on the coax
Fatigue of the solder connections - maybe wire-tie the cable to the board beyond the connection
Copper pad adhesion to the board - maybe run some vias through the pad if stray capacitance and matching permits
Quality control of the manual soldering process
Complicates board test and handling having a cable permanently attached


In practice I think it would be advisable or even necessary to tin at least the coax as a preparatory operation, to ensure that nothing wicks up too far.
